# Word: put page numbering on alternating sides of page

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers, word-2013-preview

I want to have some of page numbers on the left hand side, and some on the right hand side. I know you can do this by simply enabling the option in Word. But I have a restriction: I want to be able to choose on which side a page number has to appear. This is necessary because every new chapter has to start as a 'front page' which means the page number has to be at the right hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bb010g [said](https://superuser.com/a/520095), “Make sure all your new chapters are on either even or odd pages, …”

I add, “… by inserting a “Section Break (Even Page)” or a “Section Break (Odd Page)”.

Comment: Indeed. I already found this solution else where on the Internet, but thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your new chapters are on either even or odd pages, then use the Different Odd & Even Pages option. You may have some blank space, but that looks to be the only way, as you cannot set individual headers in Word.

Comment: Well, that seems a bit of a hassle. That would mean I should invent a whole page of content so every new chapter starts on an odd page. Cannot do that.

Comment: Or a blank page.

Comment: I suppose that could be done.